# expo: how to prevent crashes

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

When I use Expo, sometimes, on components that work perfectly on the web, the app runs on an Android phone (via Expo Go app preview) and crashes without any error feedback. Typically, this is due to an invalid style or other code that is invalid on Android, but having the app crashing is a pain in the ass to debug.

I tried using [react-native-error-boundary](https://react-native-error-boundary.js.org/), but this kind of error ignores the error boundary. What can I do?